# Is there a way to mute internal speakers on startup without unplugging headphones?

Tags: audio, startup, speakers

Some backstory: I use my MacBook at odd hours and don't want to disturb anybody with the loud startup chime. As you may well know, you can mute that by pressing the Mute key before shutdown with the headphones unplugged (otherwise, you'll just be muting the headphones). That's fine if you'll never need to use the int. speakers but I switch between them and my headphones during the day and sometimes I'll belatedly remember the need to mute but I've already plugged the headphones in.

So is there an alternative to mute the startup sound independent of having headphones plugged in or not?

Comment: How do you mute internal speakers by unplugging headphones?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish here? Where does the need of muting the internal speakers come from while headphones are plugged in (internal speakers are disabled in this case)? Do you just want to make sure that your computer is muted *whenever* you unplug your headset?

Comment: @nohillside, Nimesh Neema Some backstory: I use my MacBook at odd hours and don't want to disturb anybody with the loud startup chime. As you may well know, you can mute that by pressing the F10 key _before_ shutdown with the headphones unplugged (otherwise, you'll just be muting the headphones). That's fine if you'll never need to use the int. speakers but I switch between them and my headphones during the day and sometimes I'll belatedly remember the need to mute but I've already plugged the headphones in. Hence, I wish I could just mute the machine without unplugging (to avoid wear).

Comment: Thanks for the addition and sharing the important detail of muting the startup sound. I've edited the question accordingly, feel free to amend if I left out something.